# Does Gremlin support Namespace?

Tags: gremlin

I'd like to create different graphs based on different domain. So, a kind of namespace or schema are needed. Just like the "Schema" conception in RDBMS. Therefore, does Gremlin support Namespace or similar sth?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notion of a schema name in the Gremlin language that is exactly like what you typically have in SQL. Your Gremlin query is bound to the graph to which you connect. If you have two or more domains then you either:

1. Create one graph per domain in which you can't traverse across those domains (you'd have to combine results after traversals - without explicit edges, i.e. joins, to connect the domains Gremlin has no way to do those sorts of queries), or
2. Create one large graph to house both domains and then constrain your traversal to the domain (in TinkerPop this is sometimes accomplished with [PartitionStrategy](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_partitionstrategy))